# Importing relational data into SQL Server using XML

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've been using XML to import large amounts of data into SQL for a while now, but I am wondering if its possible to import data across multiple tables from a single XML file that has child nodes?

Given this example:

```
DECLARE @tbl_makes TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), makeName nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl_makes (makeName) VALUES ('Ford') 
INSERT INTO @tbl_makes (makeName) VALUES ('Jaguar') 

DECLARE @tbl_models TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), makeID int, modelName nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl_models (makeID, modelName) VALUES (1, 'Escort')
INSERT INTO @tbl_models (makeID, modelName) VALUES (1, 'Sierra')
INSERT INTO @tbl_models (makeID, modelName) VALUES (2, 'XK')
INSERT INTO @tbl_models (makeID, modelName) VALUES (2, 'XJS')

SELECT * FROM @tbl_makes m INNER JOIN @tbl_models md ON m.ID = md.makeID 

DECLARE @xml XML = '
<cars>
    <make name="Ford">
        <model name="Mustang" />
        <model name="Taurus" />
        <model name="F350" />
    </make>
    <make name="Aston Martin">
        <model name="Vanquish" />
        <model name="DB7" />
        <model name="Lagonda" />
    </make>
</cars>'
```

I appreciate that the make names would need to be inserted/looked-up first before related data could be inserted.  I've searched online for answers to this, but examples only use a single table. I'm guessing it's not possible without using various temporary tables, but here goes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about such solution?

```
INSERT INTO @tbl_makes (makeName)
SELECT i.i.value('@name', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/cars[1]/make')i(i)
LEFT JOIN @tbl_makes MA on i.i.value('@name', 'nvarchar(100)') = MA.makeName
WHERE MA.ID IS NULL;

INSERT INTO @tbl_models (makeID, modelName)
SELECT MA.ID, j.j.value('@name', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/cars[1]/make')i(i)
INNER JOIN @tbl_makes MA ON i.i.value('@name', 'nvarchar(100)') = MA.makeName
CROSS APPLY i.i.nodes('model')j(j)
LEFT JOIN @tbl_models MO on j.j.value('@name', 'nvarchar(100)') = MO.modelName
WHERE MO.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Wow.  Superb answer. Can you please explain the CROSS APPLY part?  Is it because you can't LEFT JOIN to an XML object value?  Also, would OUTER APPLY have made any difference to the logic?

Comment: CROSS APPLY and nodes() help to create a table-like entity from XML document. XPath expression returns some elements, and every single element is associated with single row. You may need OUTER APPLY only if there can be car makers without any cars mentioned.